# interactive graph php mysql javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, graphics, charts

I have a website where user enter information daily, i want to present that information in an interactive graph. i have made the website using php/mysql, any ideas?

i want something like this

http://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=z8o7pt6rd5uqa6_&ctype=l&met_y=unemployment_rate&fdim_y=country_group:eu&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=sex&idim=sex:f:m&hl=en_US&dl=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [FusionCharts Free](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/) or another interactive charting component. It will be significantly easier than trying to code one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), a graphing library written in JavaScript. It's free for non-commercial use or there's a reasonable single-site fee or developer's licence.

Comment: Since it seems his data is from MySQL, it might be complicated to use a JavaScript-only graphing solution, as he would need to code his own PHP data extractor, that produces data that fits with the HighCharts API.

Comment: FusionCharts provides a bundled PHP script that helps him interface with the database. See this tutorial - http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/03/javascript-charts-using-php-and-mysql-with-fusioncharts-xt-part-2/